# Edit all cells of column in Pandas DataFrame conditionally using original value of each cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to edit all cells of one column (here column named "Links") in Pandas DataFrame **conditionally using original value of each cell**.

I know how to modify each cell of column, but don't know how to edit cell using original value of cell **and** make modification conditionally.

I have simple sample of Data Frame:

[image]

I am interested in last column "Links".

If cell endwswith .html I need to change it to:

```
<A> <original value> </A>
```

for example:

> /l/sf-49ers/456346aaa.html

if it is number I need to make:

```
some-domain.info/number
```

for example:

> some-domain.info/343

If it is text (string):

I need to put it in B tags:

for example:

> **"Baltimore Rayens"**

If it is None I need to replace it with text "No link specified".

---

I have used this syntax:

```
def change_links(df):
    conditions = (..........)
    values = [.......................]
    df['Links'] = np.select(conditions, values)
    return df
```

but this does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you correct, you need to use apply function:

```
def change_links(link):
    if 'html' in link:
        newLink=0 #here change your link
    elif link[-1].isdigit():
        newLink='some-domain.info/'+str(link) #or do what you nedd
    else:
        newLink=1 #here add your tags
    return newLink
df['newLink'] = df['Links'].apply(lambda x(change_links(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is kinda messy, I am answering your question based on what I have understood. You have two options in front of you:

- `apply`
- `map`

in either cases you simply need to do something like what follows:

```py
def myCustomFunc(valueOfRow):
  # you need to change the value inside this function.
  return valueOfRow + "/more-link"
df["Link"] = df["Link"].apply(myCustomFunc)
```

If you are interested in map, you can use `map` function instead of `apply` in the abovementioned cell.

Comment: Thanks for very very fast reply (I don't even finished writing my question, as I am not 100% familiar with SO editor yet), I will test it with my DF and write if it works. The last line is correct? Shouldn't be: df["Link"] = df["Link"].apply(myCustomFunc) ?

Comment: Thanks, this  (after small change) works for me!

Comment: @PrertoQuebas Thanks for the heads up! Yeah, the last line should be as exactly as what you said. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a formatting probleme in your question, but you can achieve what you want with the function `apply()`

```py
def myFunction(value):
    # For example for a int
    new_value = "some-domain.info/" + str(value)

    return new_value

df['Links'] = df.['Links'].apply(myFunction)
```

I could complete the answer with more information.